# Modifying binary ARMv7 library to work with ARMv6

Tags: arm, cpu-architecture

Is it possible to programmatically alter a ARMv7-compiled binary to replace all the new opcodes and instructions with ARMv6 compatible ones?

I don't really care that much about performance at this point, I just want to use some ARMv7 only binaries on an ARMv6 (with vfp, if that matters).

Comment: If you're asking about in-place replacement then the answer is no. If you have some very smart code that can adjust branch offsets, then it might be possible, but quite complex. If the ARMv7 code contains NEON instructions, then it would be even more difficult. ARMv7 versus ARMv6 brings the Thumb2 and NEON instruction sets. Not easy to go backwards.

Comment: You might be able to do that, by replacing v7 instructions with branch instructions and then emulating the former instruction with v6 code and jumping back to the original code. Another solution could be kernel-level code which emulates invalid instructions. The second one could be the easier implementation, but it would be quite slow. But both solutions are a tremendous amount of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vfp will matter if using instructions not supported on ARMv6 unless those are the ones you are replacing.

If we are talking just arm instructions not armv6 it is probably a short list.  It is probably reducing the number of instructions though so you would have to modify the code such that the armv7 instruction causes a branch somewhere, that somewhere is the replacment code using armv6 or older instructions, then branch back.  not branch and link, unconditional branch or ldr pc,something, etc.  if you are talking about thumb2 stuff that may still be possible but 
probably more work, some things you might not be able to do.

short answer: Yes in general this kind of thing can be done.